# Extract word after specific word from text file and put into XML file between specific tag

Tags: xml, batch-file, command, text-files

I need to Read a value from text file and put that value between tags of a XML file using batch commands.

The text file. text.txt

Input:

```
First 10
Second 13
Intersection aktivieren
```

Output file : data.xml

```
<First>10</First>
<Second>13</Second>
```

Comment: Accordingly to your example, why the last output line is not `<Intersection>aktivieren</Intersection>`?

Comment: I needed only first two parameters to be added. I got the answer. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible batch code for this task is:

```
@echo off
if not exist "text.txt" goto :EOF
del "data.xml" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%I in ("text.txt") do echo ^<%%I^>%%J^</%%I^>>>"data.xml"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

The angle brackets of the XML tags must be escaped with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal characters and not as redirection operators.

Of course the third line in `data.xml` is `<Intersection>aktivieren</Intersection>`.

The following batch file code could be used to process only lines with `First` or `Second` (case-insensitive) as first space/tab delimited string.

```
@echo off
if not exist "text.txt" goto :EOF
del "data.xml" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%I in ("text.txt") do (
    if /I "%%I" == "First" (
        echo ^<%%I^>%%J^</%%I^>>>"data.xml"
    ) else if /I "%%I" == "Second" (
        echo ^<%%I^>%%J^</%%I^>>>"data.xml"
    )
)
```